# Bash - Single Quotes Being Added to Spaces

Tags: bash, docker, string-interpolation

I have the following:
test.ini

```
BUILD_ARGS='--build-arg user="test user" --build-arg pass=testPass'
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
source test.ini
docker build -t test:test ${BUILD_ARGS} .
```

Output of test.sh

```
+ source test.ini
++ BUILD_ARGS='--build-arg smb_user="test user" --build-arg smb_pass=testPass '
+ docker build -t test:test --build-arg 'user="test' 'user"' --build-arg pass=testPass .
```

Why are extra single quotes being added in between "test" and "user"? I would expect the command to be executed as:

```
docker build -t test:test --build-arg user="test user" --build-arg pass=testPass .
```

Comment: This is normal, expected behavior. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and don't try to use strings to store lists; only *arrays* are appropriate for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments needs to be constructed as an array:

```
BUILD_ARGS=(--build-arg user="test user" --build-arg pass="testPass")

docker build -t test:test "${BUILD_ARGS[@]}"
```